# Eclipse/LibGDXgame doesn't load textures

Tags: libgdx, eclipse

Our LibGDX project doesn't load textures after building on PC/Android but when it's built from Eclipse using  Ctrl + F11 (Run/Debug) everything is fine. What could be causing that?

Comment: Typically you should include error messages for this type of situation. In fact, had you looked at the error messages, you'd probably find that they were errors about not being able to find the textures and you might have been able to solve this yourself. Simple troubleshooting is always easier than posting to the web and waiting for a response.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running your application from different working directories. Check the project settings in Eclipse and look for "Debug Directory" or similar. If you run you program from withing that same directory outside Eclipse it will probably work fine.